# Append type arguments cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sha1

I have to encrypt a string using SHA1 using a specific format and I have declared my variable types but I can't figure out why this error persists.

```
string sb = "";

using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
{
    byte[] byteHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HashData));

    foreach (byte bh in byteHash)
    {
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", bh));
    }
}
```

My exact error is :

> The type arguments for method
>   'Enumerable.Append(IEnumerable, TSource)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: did you mean to use `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` or did you mean to say `sb.Concat(...)`? Does this compile for you?

Comment: string does not have `Append` method. Is that an extension method?

Comment: @KSib no it doesn't compile. I'm working with an third party and they specifically gave me this sample to build the hash.

Comment: Declare sb as a `StringBuilder` (which is probably what `sb` was supposed to stand for), and when you're done you can get the string by calling `sb.ToString()`

Comment: @RufusL You're probably right that didn't even cross my mind. They handed me just a fragment of a snippet, I figured they would give all pertinent code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare `sb` as a `StringBuilder` (which is probably what "sb" was supposed to stand for), and when you're done you can get the string by calling `sb.ToString()`

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
{
    byte[] byteHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HashData));

    foreach (byte bh in byteHash)
    {
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", bh));
    }
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```